# Best way to define a bespoke Card in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

[image]

I've been attempting to define a bespoke Card in Flutter using `row` and `column` and cannot seem to get a fixed format layout similar to the image above (the red lines denote the areas of the card and are just there to show the areas).

e.g.

```
return Card(child: Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Column( children: [
          Text('Riverside cafe...'),
          Ratingbar(),
        ],),
        ImageWidget(),
      ],
    ),
    Container(child: Text('Pubs & restaurants'), color : Colors.purple)
  ],
```

The resulting cards are to be displayed in a `listview` and using `rows` and `columns` above results in the areas being different sized depending on the data.

It seems to me that using `row` and `column` may not be the best way to achieve this. Is there a better way?

Comment: it all depends how it should look if your "Riverside cafe with a long name" is for example full "lorem ipsum" - would you still expect two lines of text?

Comment: If it's the sizing of the widgets that you are struggling with, you can wrap all the components in a Flexible widget and use the flex argument to fix the relative sizes of your widgets

Comment: Its getting the sizing of the red bounded areas consistent (and also colouring the whole of the bottom area (and not just the text)

Answer (score 1):

As for the best, I suppose that's for you and your client to decide.

For as long as I've been working with Flutter, I haven't come across anything like CSS grid which is great for situations like this. The closest comparison is StaggeredGrid (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) but that doesn't offer as much control as CSS grid and doesn't seem to quite fit your use case.

Rows, Columns (and other layout widgets) can get the job done:
[image]

Here's the main.dart that produced the above example. Code quality isn't perfect, but hopefully you can follow it well enough and it helps you get done what you need to get done.

```dart
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Bespoke card example';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bespoke card example')),
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(runSpacing: 10.0, children: [
          BespokeCard(title: 'Short name', width: 350),
          BespokeCard(
              title: 'Riverside Cafe with a really long name', width: 350)
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BespokeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double width;
  BespokeCard({this.title, this.width});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _restaurantNameContainer = Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 0,
        maxHeight: 120,
        maxWidth: (500.0 - 40 - 175 + 1),
        minWidth: (500.0 - 40 - 175 + 1),
      ),
      child: AutoSizeText(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
        maxLines: 2,
        minFontSize: 10,
        stepGranularity: 0.1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    );
    Widget _rightSideSection = Container(
      width: 175,
      height: Size.infinite.height,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.umbrella,
          size: 70,
        ),
      ),
    );
    Widget _topSection = Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 25.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Flexible(child: Container(), flex: 1),
                  _restaurantNameContainer,
                  Text('* * * * *', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          _rightSideSection
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget _bottomSection = Container(
        height: 70,
        width: Size.infinite.width,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Pubs & Restaurants',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40)),
        ),
        color: Colors.purple);

    Widget unfittedCard = Card(
        child: SizedBox(
      width: 500,
      height: 300,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [_topSection, _bottomSection],
      ),
    ));
    return Container(
        width: this.width,
        child: FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, child: unfittedCard));
  }
}
```

NOTES:

- Be aware of flexFit (tight or loose) property: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/fit.html
- You can either define fixed ratios with all flexibles, or you can mix Flexibles with Containers / SizedBoxes what have you
- The package auto_size_text is great for situations like this. (Add `auto_size_text: ^2.1.0` to your dependencies)
- Be aware of box constraints. I needed them to make the title autosizing text be able to grow tall without also sitting in a large container.
- Fitted box is really handy and makes scaling very easy in flutter.